# How Do You Lock the Height \ Width Aspect Ratio of a Xib?

Tags: swift

I am creating a Xib whose FileOwner is set to a custom UIImageView class.  When I add this Xib to my ViewController I want the Xib to maintain an aspect ratio [width:height] of [2:1].  The user can redraw it to be any size [for example, [600:300] or [400:200] but I want the aspect ratio to remain [2:1].  Is there a way to impose this limit on a Xib?

Comment: Size of xib view display is meaningless. Up to you to size it when you load it.

Comment: I'm creating a CustomControl that will be used by other developers. Let's say a user draws a UIView named myView that is 400 x 400 [W x H].  I then set myView's custom class to be CustomControl.  Should I write code within CustomControl that resizes myView to be [400 x 200] to achieve the desired ratio of [2:1]?  If so, someone using my CustomControl won't know the size of myView until he runs his program.  I would like the CustomControl to resize itself within the XCode development environment.  Is it possible to set constraint limits on a custom control within the design environment?

Comment: If that was your question, why didn't you ask it? That comment is much more informative and interesting than the question you actually asked...! Anyway, I'm afraid the answer is mostly no. Design is not layout. IB tries to help by showing you _some_ layout results, but it can't do everything (self-sizing table cells are a case in point). You can hard-code an intrinsic content size setting, and you can make your view `@IBDesignable`, but that's as far as you can go.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can design your view for when the app runs, but you cannot design someone else’s design.